# MSSQL Insert values from table2 into table1 using condition from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `table1` and `table2` I need to migrate some data from `table2` into `table1` by matching or using a condition from both tables.
What I need is something like:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl1(VAR1,VAR2)
SELECT VAR1, VAR2 
FROM Tbl2
WHERE Tbl1.Name = Tbl2.Name and Tbl1.City = Tbl2.City
```

I have a sample schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02305/2)

Comment: just use `FROM Tbl2, Tbl1`

Comment: @RadimBača, tell people to do explicit `JOIN` instead!

Comment: @jarlh yes sir! (to mb14: however, you can use `FROM Tbl2, Tbl1` ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need update not insert

```
update Tbl1

set Tbl1.VAR1= Tbl2.VAR1,
    Tbl1.VAR2= Tbl2.VAR2

FROM Tbl2 join Tbl1 
on Tbl1.Name = Tbl2.Name and Tbl1.ADDRESS = Tbl2.ADDRESS
```

[one line demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e264b48064c5509b2c242321dead222)

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a inner join for  select the right result from both the tables

```
  INSERT INTO Tbl1(VAR1,VAR2)
  SELECT VAR1, VAR2 
  FROM Tbl2
  INNER JOIN tbl1 ON Tbl1.Name = Tbl2.Name 
  and Tbl1.City = Tbl2.City
```